# How to make popup menu with right click on GridControl row?

Tags: devexpress, contextmenu, right-click, gridcontrol

I have a GridControl with some rows on my DevExpress interface. When I right-click on some row of the grid I want to pop-up the same kind of menu like when i right-click on my desktop(win 7), but only with 3 options - Cut, Paste and Copy.

How to make this? Is there a way to say in the property editor of the GridControl "for every row if right-click then popup a Menu". If so, is this menu stored in a repository and what type is this menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the GridView's [ShowGridMenu](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_ShowGridMenutopic) event to show the context menu when a gridRow is clicked.  We have also published an example showing how this event can be used:

[How to show a context menu for grid rows](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E712)

Comment: The Method ShowGridMenu is marked as "Obsolete". They say: "You should use the '[PopupMenuShowing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraSchedulerSchedulerControl_PopupMenuShowingtopic)' instead".

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a DevXpress.ExtraBars.BarManager Control.
2. Add a DevXpress.ExtraBars.PopupMenu Control.
3. Create your menu structure inside the PopupMenu control.
4. Add this code into the 'PopupMenuShowing' event of your GridView:

   ```
   private void gridView1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e) 
   {
       if (e.HitInfo.InRow) 
       {
           System.Drawing.Point p2 = Control.MousePosition;
           this.popupMenu1.ShowPopup(p2);
       }
   }
   ```

That's It!